# Make imageview dynamically load images from latest posts on a website

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview

I have an app and it's main layout has an imageview and a textview. I want the imageview to load whatever image is the thumbnail from the website and the text to load the title of the post on the website. Layout looks like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/942337-UltraLinx-Mobile-Site?list=searches&tag=ultralinx). Thanks in advance.

I have scoured the internet to no avail, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing 'ready-made' available.

You'll have to:

- Find what's the website API (or create one);
- make a call to this API to acquire the site data (usually as JSON or XML);
- parse that data into meaningful information;
- download the image (usually as a Bitmap object);
- and set this Bitmap to the ImageView using the method `.setImageBitmap(Bitmap);`

Comment: hmmmm, so the site I'm looking into is a wordpress powered site (http://theultralinx.com/) and there's no API for the site.... does that mean I'll have to make one myself or it won't work at all?

Comment: This will also require a timer, so to check if the website content has changed. This will have to go after step 1 and if there's something new, then steps 2-5 should be followed - do you agree?

Comment: I do agree. I have done minimal json parsing with the Facebook SDK. Will it be similar?

Comment: you can install a wordpress plugin on it, e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/ I've used that before for an similar app